# Cors error while downloading image from S3

Tags: javascript, amazon-s3

I am converting a div into an downloadable image.

```
function generateBanner() {
    domtoimage.toBlob(document.getElementById('wrapper'))
    .then(function(blob) {
      console.log("blob", blob)
      window.saveAs(blob, 'my-node.png');
    });
}
```

This code works fine.
My problem is when this div has an image that is hosted in a S3 Bucket

for example:

```
<article id="wrapper">
    <p>{{ title }}</p>
    <img class="logo" src="{{ logo }}" alt="">
    <aside class="exclusive" ng-if="exclusive"></aside>
    <aside class="off" ng-if="percentoff">{{ percentoff }}
    </aside>
    <div class="produtos">
        <img src="https://s3-sa-east-1.amazonaws.com/teste-img-roge/Thumbs/0026954_30510_1_415.jpeg" alt="">
    </div>
    <aside class="valid" ng-if="valid"></aside>
    </article>
```

after that, when I click I got CORS errors, and I have no idea why.

In my s3 Configuration I have this:

```
<CORSConfiguration>
   <CORSRule>
 <AllowedOrigin>*</AllowedOrigin>
  <AllowedMethod>GET</AllowedMethod>
   <AllowedMethod>POST</AllowedMethod>
   <MaxAgeSeconds>3000</MaxAgeSeconds>
   <AllowedHeader>*</AllowedHeader>
   </CORSRule>
   </CORSConfiguration>
```

and still the same error. Any idea ? I tried few different configs in s3, and few approachs with javascript, but none of them worked.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You're missing `<AllowedMethod>HEAD</AllowedMethod>`

Then you should see the following headers:

```
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, HEAD, POST
Access-Control-Max-Age: 3000
```

Have in mind, that it could take a while before you see the correct headers.

Comment: @MarcosCasagrande will you help me understand how you identified this as the problem?  I don't understand what, in the question, made you suspect that `HEAD` requests were being made.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot to be honest, experience. I had the same issues in the past with S3 and CORS. When I had those issues, I tried all the valid methods, and without `HEAD` it just didn't work. I couldn't find any documentation on this, so all I have is my experience working with S3.

Comment: Interesting.  There's a [bug](https://serverfault.com/a/856948/153161) in S3 that prevents CORS from working correctly when you access the same object from both HTML and XHR, and I was hoping it would not also be applicable here.  It looks like it isn't. +1 and thank you for the response.

Comment: You're welcome. And I wasn't aware of that bug, it was a great read btw.