# How to configure simple static AWS S3 image reads via Heroku/Node.js (403 access errors)

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, heroku, amazon-s3

I've been trying to configure read permissions for an AWS S3 bucket with no luck.

My use case: a private application run on Node.js/express that displays static logo image files from an S3 bucket. The image files stored in the S3 bucket should not be publicly accessible, and are only fetched to appear in the views in my app. For the purposes of this question, I am literally serving a single HTML page that contains a single image element.

I have followed the steps in [this Heroku guide](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/s3), which suggests that if you set a valid AWS key pair (representing an AWS role with proper credentials) and S3 bucket name in Heroku's config variables, you should simply be able to insert the link to the S3 image file into your HTML, and it should render on the site.

Most of my time thus far has been playing with AWS permissions on the S3 bucket and on the IAM role I am using.

Here is what I have done so far:

1. On AWS, I create an IAM user called "userx" with "Programmatic access" (i.e. a generated key pair). During user creation, I set permissions via "Attach existing policies directly" and attach the "AmazonS3FullAccess" policy to my new user. Let's say this user has an ARN of "arn:aws:iam::12345:user/userx"
2. With a new user generated (and a new Access Key ID + Secret Access Key), I update my Heroku configuration in a terminal window via:

   heroku config:set AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=123MYACCESSKEYID

Followed by:

```
heroku config:set AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=123MYSECRETKEYxyz
```

3. I create an AWS S3 bucket called 'my-assets' and set permissions to "Do not grant public read access to this bucket." I upload a single image file to this bucket: myimage.png. I set the bucket permissions by generating a new bucket policy and attaching it to the bucket:

```js
    {
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Id": "Policy1528038465156",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "Stmt1528038463415",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::12345:user/userx"
            },
            "Action": "s3:*",
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::my-assets",
                "arn:aws:s3:::my-assets/*"
            ]
        }
      ]
    }
```

On heroku, I set the bucket name via:

```
heroku config:set S3_BUCKET_NAME=my-assets
```

4. I set the CORS configuration on my bucket as follows:

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<CORSConfiguration xmlns="http://s3.amazonaws.com/doc/2006-03-01/">
<CORSRule>
    <AllowedOrigin>*</AllowedOrigin>
    <AllowedMethod>GET</AllowedMethod>
    <AllowedMethod>POST</AllowedMethod>
    <AllowedMethod>PUT</AllowedMethod>
    <AllowedHeader>*</AllowedHeader>
</CORSRule>
</CORSConfiguration>
```

On heroku, I restart my server, and launch my app, which is currently serving a single html file with one element:

```
<<img src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/my-assets/myimage.png" />
```

In my chrome terminal, when the page loads, the request to the S3 bucket fails with a 403 Forbidden error.

My understanding is that - for a simple situation of fetching static files - Heroku should handle the GET request to my S3 bucket, signing the request with the key pair I loaded into it's config variables, and that request should have access to read the image file from my S3 bucket because of the IAM, bucket policy, and CORS config given above.

I've triple checked my key pairs, etc. Am I correct in thinking don't need to do anything to configure the request coming from heroku to AWS (i.e. I don't need to be using the AWS SDK or anything like that)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This has nothing to do with heroku, heroku is not serving your files, your're accesing s3 directly from your browser.

If you want to serve the files directly from s3, you have to give those files public read permissions.

To make a file public, just:

`click file > More > Make public`

You will need access keys if you want to upload/read files from a private bucket from your server, but you won't need them if you're requesting from your browser an image hosted in S3, which has public read access.

Regarding your CORS configuration, you can check this question:

[Cors error while downloading image from S3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50381069/cors-error-while-downloading-image-from-s3/50381106#50381106)

---

If you want to keep your file private, and only allow some authenticated users to view them, you can use `aws-sdk` to generate a signed S3 URL, and use that URL on your browser.

```
const AWS = require('aws-sdk')

const s3 = new AWS.S3()
AWS.config.update({ 
    accessKeyId: 'keyId', 
    secretAccessKey: 'accessKey'
})

const params = {
    Bucket: 'bucket-name',
    Key: 'my-assets/myimage.png',
    Expires: 60 // Seconds
};

(async() => {

    s3.getSignedUrl('getObject', params, (err, url) => {
        console.log(url);

        // This is the URL that you need to use on your HTML
    });

})();
```

Comment: Thank you - that was my original assumption. But because Heroku had a guide on serving static files that explicitly walked through setting AWS creds as config vars, and then just said "Once uploaded your application can reference its assets by copying their public URLs (such as http://s3.amazonaws.com/bucketname/filename) and pasting them directly into your app’s views or HTML files" I though Heroku somehow handled this.

For my use case (serving static images that aren't publicly accessible), do you know if using AWS-SDK would be the best method?

Comment: If you're going to serve the anyway, why not make them public (read only)?

Comment: The application involves some image files (charts) that have private business information, and I don't want them to be publicly available over the internet.

Comment: Then what do you want to do with those images? Dont make those public, just the one you want to show on your browser. If you want to serve images only to logged users, tell me so.

Comment: Yes - I'm looking to server those images (i.e. include those image files in my views) only to logged in users.